# getsupportfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map) returns null Google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I try to use google map functionality on my MainActivity I have this null pointer returned by : 
getsupportfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map); ==> return null

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapApi);
```

mapfragment will be null and when I call it using getMapAsync(this); the app shut down before it starts

```
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // null pointer variable call getMapAsync
```

content_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapApi"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
```

onCreate inside the MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener , OnMapReadyCallback {



    private GoogleMap map;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); didn't work
setContentView(R.layout.content_main); // worked, now i haven't null pointer 
        System.out.println("************************ mapApi:"+R.id.mapApi);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapApi);


        System.out.println("************************ mapFragment:"+mapFragment);

        if (mapFragment != null) {

            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    LatLng BordjMenaielGare = new LatLng(36.753162, 3.717716);
    LatLng Blida = new LatLng(36.769038, 3.057451);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BordjMenaielGare).title("Gare Bordj Menaiel "));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Blida).title("Gare Agha"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BordjMenaielGare, 10));
}
```

}

here are the files :

the map fragment is on content_main.xml, I included it in app_bar_main.xml, and app_bar_main included in activity_main.xml and I'm calling the map from MainActivity

[image]

I searched a lot in StackOverflow but none of the solutions are valid for my case

can someone help me with this?

Comment: what is the id of your map in the xml `mapApi` or `map`  ? you seem to have two different names so this could be the reason...

Comment: it is mapApi i just used it for the title to be generic

Comment: can you share the onCreate method of your activity? and your xml

Comment: of course, post edited now

Comment: `getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: show xml please.

Comment: show xml done |    i'm tring getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

Comment: where is `setContentView`???

Comment: Do I have to extend FrameLayout in place of AppCompatActivity ?? what do you think about it, is it caused by  extends AppCompatActivity, I used AppCompatActivity because I need it in another place of code, so what do you think devs ?

Comment: no thats not the issue, can you share the activity_name.xml? it looks like you have the map fragment I the content_main.xml is this included?

Comment: please post the activity_name.xml

Comment: Done ! : please post the activity_name.xm

Comment: can you update your onCreate to include the setContentView call

Comment: yes, it didn't affect the results,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call:

```
// add this (supplying the layout for your activity)
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

after your call to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Same issue, I added it after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and nothing happened

Comment: `@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);` ??

Comment: yes bro :     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);